# access Broadcast Variables in Spark java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, lookup, rdd, broadcast

I need to process spark Broadcast variables using Java RDD API. This is my code what I have tried so far:

This is only sample code to check whether its works or not? In my case I need to work on two `csv`files.

```
          SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("BroadcastVariable").setMaster("local");
          JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
          Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
          map.put(1, "aa");
          map.put(2, "bb");
          map.put(9, "ccc");
          Broadcast<Map<Integer, String>> broadcastVar = ctx.broadcast(map);
          List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          list.add(1);
          list.add(2);
          list.add(9);
          JavaRDD<Integer> listrdd = ctx.parallelize(list);
          JavaRDD<Object> mapr = listrdd.map(x -> broadcastVar.value());
          System.out.println(mapr.collect());
```

and it prints output like this:

```
[{1=aa, 2=bb, 9=ccc}, {1=aa, 2=bb, 9=ccc}, {1=aa, 2=bb, 9=ccc}]
```

and my requirement is :

```
 [{aa, bb, ccc}]
```

Is it possible to do like in my required way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `JavaRDD<Object> mapr = listrdd.map(x -> broadcastVar.value().get(x));`
insted of `JavaRDD<Object> mapr = listrdd.map(x -> broadcastVar.value());`.

Its working now.

Comment: is this working in cluster , i have same requirement but it is not working as expected  .withColumn("five", lit(((Map<Integer, Integer>)lookUpMapBcVar.getValue()).get(5))  
          )
    .withColumn("map_code3", lit(((Map<Integer, Integer>)lookUpMapBcVar.getValue()).get(col("floor_code3_int")))  
          )
    
    .withColumn("five_lit", lit(((Map<Integer, Integer>)lookUpMapBcVar.getValue()).get(lit(5).cast(DataTypes.IntegerType))) 
          )
    ;      Except this ---( lookUpMapBcVar.getValue()).get(5))  )  -- nothing is working ...